# Problem with Webserver

Tags: apache2, php, wordpress, websites

When I create a web server it was working ok but now when I go to my site this shows instead of the website

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: Have you installed `php` and the need `php modules`?

Comment: Have you installed php and the needed php modules?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the text of your index.php rather than running it because apache is not running. Try

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

More documentation on running apache can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).